# RabbitMQ / amqplib -- Error: Frame size exceeds frame max

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp, node-amqplib

Connection to RabbitMQ fails with `Error: Frame size exceeds frame max`.

Although there are a few similar issues raised on StackOverflow and Github, but it is still very vague.

One assumes that the version of AMQP used by RabbitMQ and amqplib differs, but how to check that? If talking about major differences of `amqp 1.0` and `amqp 0-9-1`, then theoretically amqplib only supports 0-9-1 and RabbitMQ supports it by default.

Any other ideas?

Versions:

- RabbitMQ: 3.10.5
- amqplib: 0.10.0

Comment: I need code to reproduce this issue. What is in the RabbitMQ logs? How are you running RabbitMQ and your application? Is there a load balancer in place?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an instance on the amqps dashboard, a URL owuld be generated after a successful instance creation. Use the URL.
This worked for me.

https://api.cloudamqp.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem of "**Frame size exceeds frame max**" error on connecting to `RabbitMQ` was due to missing "s" in the protocol part of the URL (so instead of `amqp`:// it was supposed to be `amqps`://)